# Scripting a Windows 2008 Cluster from Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, cluster, failover

Our current environment is all Windows 2003.  When we migrate a new version of our service to the cluster, we first stop the service with a command like:

```
cluster.exe <clusterName> resource "<serviceName>" /offline
```

We do similarly after the migrate to bring the service back online.

Now, we are upgrading our environment to new Windows 2008 servers.  However, our build/migrate machine will remain Windows 2003.  When issuing the same command from Windwos 2003 to Windows 2008, we get:

```
System error 1722 has occurred (0x000006ba).
The RPC server is unavailable.
```

We need to be able to remotely administer a Windows 2008 cluster from a Windows 2003 server in an automated fashion (such as the command-line cluster.exe utility).  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Gideon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The `cluster.exe` command from Windows Server 2003 is just not compatible with Windows Server 2008 failover clustering, neither is the Cluster Administrator MMC.

I was actually testing this in an Exchange 2010 lab just a couple of hours ago... and I have absolutely NO firewall there (first thing I disable when testing something).

No cluster management from 2003 to 2008, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a firewall issue. By default, 2008 protect all inbound.

2 ways:

- Activate inbound RPC
- Disable firewall

As a quick test, disable the firewall, through this command, locally inside an elevated command line:

> netsh advfirewall set currentprofile state off

Comment: I do not believe there is a firewall on this server (and I am not the admin of it, so I cannot run your command).

I should point out, though, that I can use cluster as described when I am going from a Windows 2008 box to a Windows 2008 box--just NOT from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008, which is what I need.

Thanks for your reply,
Gideon

Comment: how can you stop a cluster resource without being admin ? Just a specific right allowed on your account ?
2008 is the last version where cluster.exe is shipped, i recommend you switch to powershell as soon as you can (and do the powershell from 2003 or 2008)
The firewall is there by default, and active without doing anything. Maybe they just allowed traffic from the other box. Your message is quite explicit on the 2003 not being able to reach the remote RPC

Comment: you can also check this KB:
RPC Unavailable Error appears when you try to access a cluster Server
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=258518